# Is there a good way to append JSON Data to divs only using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I created a javaScript that calls JSON data, loops through the JSON data and appends it to various divs using class names. It works good so far but it seems like I'm doing it the long way. I'm using innerHTML  `qual[0].innerHTML += data[0].size;` manually to display multiple JSON elements. In my JSON file, I know that there are 8 elements using the name "test" but the amount  (test) could change. Is there a way to loop through the JSON elements and display them via class name instead of manually writing   `qual[0].innerHTML += data[0].size; qual[1].innerHTML += data[1].size;...` ?

```
    fetch('test.json')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            appendData(data);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('error: ' + err);
        });
    function appendData(data) {
        var mainContainer = document.getElementById("List");
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var qual = document.getElementsByClassName('Size')
            qual[0].innerHTML += data[0].size;
            qual[1].innerHTML += data[1].size;
            qual[2].innerHTML += data[2].size;
            qual[3].innerHTML += data[3].size;
            qual[4].innerHTML += data[4].size;
            qual[5].innerHTML += data[5].size;
            qual[6].innerHTML += data[6].size;
            qual[7].innerHTML += data[7].size;

            mainContainer.appendChild(div);
        }
    }
```

The HTML

```
        <h1>List</h1>
        <div class="size"></div>
        <div class="size"></div>
        <div class="size"></div>
        <div class="size"></div>
        <div class="size"></div>
        <div class="size"></div>
        <div class="size"></div>
```

The JSON

```
  [
        {

           "test":"Test Data",
           "size":12
        },
        {
           "test":"Test Data",
           "size":5
        },
        {

           "test":"Pasta",
           "size":1
        },
        {

           "size":3
        },
        {

           "test":"Test Data",
           "size":8
        },
        {

           "test":"Test Data",
           "size":9
        },
        {

           "test":"Test Data",
           "size":9
        },
        {

           "test":"Test Data",
           "size":5
        }
     ]
```

I would like the dive to populate like the following:

```
   <div class="size"> 1 </div>
    <div class="size"> 2 </div>
    <div class="size"> 3 </div>
    <div class="size"> 4 </div>
    <div class="size"> 5 </div>
    <div class="size"> 6 </div>
    <div class="size"> 7 </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're defeating the purpose of using a `for` loop. Make use of the index (i) variable to loop through the array returned by `getElementsByClassName()`. Like so:

```js
    function appendData(data) {
        var mainContainer = document.getElementById("List");
        var qual = document.getElementsByClassName('Size');
        for (var j = 0; j < qual.length; j++) {
            qual[j].innerHTML += data[j].size;
        }
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Yes This is helpful but when I tried your example only the first div was populated with duplicate amounts in one div `<div class="size">12 12 12 12 ..</div>` I would like each value to populate each div

Comment: This div referenced here: `mainContainer.appendChild(div);`, where is it defined?

Comment: Also, I noticed a typo in my code. Have corrected it now

Comment: Ahh, it's not defined

Comment: Your code works but I'm getting the following error `error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'`  I believe it's being caused by `mainContainer.appendChild(div);` The problem is when I remove it. I get multiple numbers in one div

Comment: ClassName is "size" instead of "Size"

Comment: Yeah, I'm still having the duplication issue

Comment: Seems I misunderstood what you were trying to achieve. I've made some changes to my solution. Give it a try

Comment: No problem at all. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

We use a `for...of` loop for this. It loops through an array and returns the item it's currently on.

This code is going through the array and creating an element for each item within it.

```
function appendData(data) {
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById("List");
    for (const element of data) {
        mainContainer.innerHTML+="<div class=\"size\">"+element.size+"</div>"
    }
}
```

This will find an element with the id `List` and add the elements dynamically.

So you'll start with

```
<div id="List">

</div>
```

and end with

```
<div id="List">
    <div class="size">12</div>
    <div class="size">5</div>
    <div class="size">1</div>
    <div class="size">3</div>
    <div class="size">8</div>
    <div class="size">9</div>
    <div class="size">9</div>
    <div class="size">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your example but it isn't working for me. Do you have a working example?

Comment: @Spanky My appologies. I mistyped the variable name. instead of `data.size` it should be `element.size`. [Heres a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GavHern/0o8c4pav/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is snippet, using for-loop over elements

```js
 var data = [
        {

           "test":"Test Data",
           "size":12
        },
        {
           "test":"Test Data",
           "size":5
        },
        {

           "test":"Pasta",
           "size":1
        },
        {

           "size":3
        },
        {

           "test":"Test Data",
           "size":8
        },
        {

           "test":"Test Data",
           "size":9
        },
        {

           "test":"Test Data",
           "size":9
        },
        {

           "test":"Test Data",
           "size":5
        }
     ]
const items = document.getElementsByClassName("size");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].innerHTML += data[i].size
}
```

```html
        <h1>List</h1>
        <div class="size"></div>
        <div class="size"></div>
        <div class="size"></div>
        <div class="size"></div>
        <div class="size"></div>
        <div class="size"></div>
        <div class="size"></div>
```